# arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: section `.bss' will not fit in region `RAM'

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

How to debug this error?

```
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: avds.elf section `.bss' will not fit in region `RAM'
arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: region `RAM' overflowed by 14072 bytes
```

I'd like to see map of memory to find what objects consumes BSS memory.

Comment: Most tool-chains have a linker option to produce a map.

Comment: Give `-Wl,-Map,"<name of map file>"` a shot.

Comment: Too much statically declared data i guess?

Comment: @user4581301 I think you mean `-Wl,-Map=` not `-Wl,Map,`